# Using Spatial join for many to one relates in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, attribute-joins

I'm trying to do a spatial join that takes the attributes of multiple polygons and applies them to a single polygon in another layer. The data is currently in a geodatabase, but can be exported to shp if needed.

In the example below I want to end up with polygon 1 also having the attributes of the features that intersect it so A, B and C. The output doesn't have to remain as a single feature so the output layer would have features 1A, 1B and 1C.

[image: Many to one join]

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

To clarify, the output would need to maintain the geometry of 1 for all 3 output features so that they have the same area and 3 different sets of attributes rather than splitting the feature into 3 parts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [ArcGIS Spatial Join Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Spatial_Join/00080000000q000000/) with these settings:

- target_features = layer1
- join_features = layerABC
- join_operation = JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY

Answer (score 2):

If i can store your data in Postgres\Postgis or Spatialite, you can do a query like this:

```sql
SELECT
    f.*,
    g.field_1,
    g.field_2,
    g.field_3
FROM
    table_1 AS f JOIN
    table_abc AS g
    ON (ST_Intersects(f.geom, g.geom))
```

Assuming that your tables are called "table_1" and "table_abc", and that the table _abc fields that you are interested in are called "field_1", "field_2" and "field_3".