# QGIS Spatial join many points to single vector

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I've got two shape files, one contains many point coordinates and the other vector shapes. There are many point coordinates contained within each vector shape.

I would like to perform a spatial join and create a new shapefile of the coordinates but with the attributes of the overlying vector shape.

QGIS spatial join does not seem to work for this. Any ideas? Also setting up a spatial database would be the ideal solution but is not possible in the time frame required.

Thanks
Richard

Comment: See my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86987/spatial-join-many-to-one), copying the files to spatialite won't take you that long.

Comment: Hi Alex, Unfortunately spacialite is not possible right now because I have strict controls on what I can install in the work place.

Comment: If you have QGIS, I believe you have spatialite out off the box. All you need is to save as...