# Consolidating many-to-one overlapping polygon feature values into another polygon attribute using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-join, overlapping-features

I have a situation similar to the one here:
[Using Spatial join for many to one relates in ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86987/spatial-join-many-to-one)

however the desired end product is a dissolved/aggregated feature that collects up all the values it was joined to.

For example if I have PolygonA which is overlapped by Value1 and Value2 I want to produce a polygon feature class with the same geometry as PolygonA, but with an attribute value that has "Value1, Value2".

I have found some variations on answers for this, but hoping for something simple-ish that doesn't require a bunch of python (not a coder).  Hoping for a geoprocess that could handle the aggregation after a spatial join, does anything like that exist, or is there a technique to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Spatial Join tool. In the Field Map, you can right-click a Field name, select Merge Rule, select JOIN. Join acts as Concatenate. You can also define the delimiter, such as a comma, in the Properties dialog of the Field.

Comment: brilliant!  had no idea that functionality was buried in a right-click!